# Firefox addeventlistner('mouseover',...) on <button> not work

Tags: javascript, firefox, addeventlistener, event-listener

The following javascript successfully trigger `alert` on `<button>` element for Chrome but not Firefox; with Firefox, `alert` is not triggered:

```
element.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){ alert('mouseover') }, false);
```

When I replace `element` html to `<span>`, the event triggers the expected `alert` in Firefox, as expected.

Offending html:

**not working html**

```
<button id="button-upload"><span>upload</span></button>
```

**working html**

```
<span id="button-upload"><span>upload</span></span>
```

In firefox, do events not bubble to buttons from children?

If so, is there a workaround - other than replacing `button` with `span` due to css.

Comment: Might be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187854/jquery-event-bubbling-on-button-not-working-as-expected-in-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you do this instead?

html:

```
<div><button id="button-upload"><span>upload</span></button></div>
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('button-upload').parentNode.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){ alert('mouseover') }, false);
```

Comment: `<div id="button-upload"><button><span>upload</span></button></div>`

works even better :), no js change

thanks!